# Android: AudioTrack vs. multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, audiotrack

I'm facing a problem where I want to play a half second long `AudioTrack` in static mode repeatedly, but the sound is choppy. However, I noticed that the sound is perfectly clear while a `TransitionDrawable` is running in parallel.

A simplified skeleton of my code is:

```
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    createTransition();

    try {
      createAudioTrack();

      while (true) {
        if (audio) {
          playSoundClip();
        }

        if (display) {
          playScreenTransition();
        }

        Thread.sleep(getDelayBetweenBeats());
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } finally {
      resetScreenTransition();
      stopSoundClip();
    }
  }

  private void createAudioTrack() {
    short[] samples = generateSamples();
    track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLERATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, samples.length * 2, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    if (track.getState() != AudioTrack.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
      track.write(samples, 0, samples.length);
    }
  }

  private void playSoundClip() {
    if (track != null && track.getState() != AudioTrack.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
      track.stop();
      track.reloadStaticData();
      track.play();
    }
  }

  private void playScreenTransition() {
    view.post(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(transition);
        transition.startTransition(DURATION);
      }

    });
  }

});
thread.start();
```

As you can see `thread` is not performed on the UI-thread so I assume that the `track` is facing multithreading problems. I don't think that the UI-thread that plays the transition consumes the entire CPU since my audio is playing in parallel. It seems as if the activity somehow consumes the CPU and nothing else is executed.

I had tried to use `view.post(new Runnable() {...});` in `playSoundClip()`, too, but that didn't help.

I thought about changing all into an `AsyncTask`, but IMHO that wouldn't change anything as it would still be a background task. Since I don't need to update an UI-element with the sound and the transition still has to play in parallel I didn't even try that.

A solution would probably be to always have some transition running in parallel (the actual one or a dummy one), but that just sounds bad (pun?) to me.

Does anyone know of another way how I can make `track` play clear at all times?

---

EDIT:
After working some more in this issue and extending my program I noticed that I have to use a threaded approach like I lined out above as the logic in there takes some time to complete and I can't do it all on the UI-thread any more. Currently I play a dummy transition while the audio is playing, which still sounds bad to me. Therefore, if you can still contribute some insights into this topic you are welcome to post/answer them here.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at `SoundPool`, which would allow you to statically load your short audio sample into memory once and then play it on-demand with much lower latency.  The way in which you are using `AudioTrack` is a good use of replaying the audio without reloading, but it might still be a bit heavy-weight for such a short and often repeated sound byte.

You might also consider not using a background thread at all.  It looks from your snippet like you are really just using the `Thread` as a timer, and you might get better performance out of using a `Handler` to post your `Runnable` on a timed interval (which would also allow you to call your audio/transition methods on the main thread) instead.

HTH

Comment: I looked at the documentation of `SoundPool` and googled a bit. It seems as if it doesn't allow generating own samples and sending it to the speakers. As far as `Handler` is concerned I have to look some more. I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: Apologies.  I missed the part where you were generating your audio data inside of your application code.

Comment: No big deal. I think I found an [example of what you think I should do](http://code.google.com/p/android-metronome/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/TickPlayer.java) and is rather close to what I want to do. However, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have much larger chunks of audio but I have had luck playing them in a Service that I created.

P.S. Nice Pun

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) a `Service` itself is pretty simple and has to delegate long lasting stuff to separate threads. Well, it does say something about priorities over other threads. I will see what I can do with it.

Comment: That also didn't help. `startForeground()` in the service didn't help, using an additional `Handler` did neither. Are you using `AudioTrack` to play the files? Or `SoundPool` or `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: When you say the audio is choppy is it choppy when starting the audio over or within the clip its slef

Comment: The clip itself is rather short so I can't tell if it would get better some time into the clip. As far as I can tell the chops aren't always at the same positions. -- It would still be interesting to me if you use `AudioTrack` or one of the others.

Comment: My service was also running in the background aka not in the ui thread. I was using a MediaPlayer inside the service.